# How can i link two asp pages in .net?

Tags: asp.net

Say if i have a master page in that i have a button if user clicks on the button he should be redirected to new asp page how can i do that.pls help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the code-behind for the button.

```
Response.Redirect("~/SecondPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("your_url_here");
```

or

```
Server.Transfer("path_goes_here");
```

see http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's two options:

```
Response.Redirect("nextPage.aspx");
Server.Transfer("nextPage.aspx");
```

Both have disticnt advantages, so research and decide what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx